# RSA SHA256 file signing in C#.Net and verification on Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption

I want sign a file using C#.Net and verify the file using Java. I am using SHA256withRSA algorithm for file sign process. I have a code both sign and verify using Java. But I need to convert file signing process to C#. I would be much grateful if somebody give me the guidance to resolve this matter.

File signing processing in Java

```
    File file = new File(fileLocation);
    signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    signature.initSign(privateKey, new SecureRandom());

    byte [] bytes;
    try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()))) {
       bytes = new byte[1024];
        for (int read = 0; (read = is.read(bytes)) != -1;) {
            signature.update(bytes,0,read);
        }
    }

    byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();
    byte[] signatureLength = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(signatureBytes.length).array();

    byte[] version = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(1).array();
    String writeLoc = outPutLocation + File.separator + "TEST_" + FilenameUtils.getName(fileLocation);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(writeLoc));
    outputStream.write(version);
    outputStream.write(signatureLength);
    outputStream.write(signatureBytes);
    try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()))) {
        bytes = new byte[1024];
        for (int read = 0; (read = is.read(bytes)) != -1;) {
            outputStream.write(bytes,0,read);
        }
    }
    outputStream.close();
```

File verify process in Java

```
    PublicKey publicKey = this.getPublicKey(stringKey);
    this.signatureOne = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    int signedDataLen = this.getSignatureLength(fileLocation);

    if (signedDataLen == 256) {
        byte[] signature = this.getSignatureBytes(fileLocation, signedDataLen);
        if (publicKey != null) {
            this.signatureOne.initVerify(publicKey);
            if (this.signatureOne.verify(signature)) {
                this.writeVerifiedFileToNewLocation(fileLocation, outPutLocation, signedDataLen);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Usually questions "please provide code in different language" are downvoted or closed. Maybe you could try search for similar code or  implement it yourself and then ask for details when you will get blocked

Comment: The duplicate should at least get you started on writing your .NET code. If you get stuck you can ask another question, this time you can include your .NET code. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @JamesKPolk. After working for few days I could able to find the solution for this.There is no code change in the Java signed file verification part.In C#.Net only I had to do the generate RSACryptoServiceProvider object from the private raw key and sign the file.Cheers!